# Not sure how to set expiration date on Azure SaS locator

Tags: azure-storage

I'm creating a video on demand project, kind of like youtube.  I started out with the Contoso Video on Demand project referenced here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn735912.aspx and built around it.  I ran into this problem after 30 days, my videos and thumbnails stopped working.  It was because the SaS created when I published these assets to my storage account expired after 30 days.

My website allows for any user (annonymous users as well as authenticated ones) to view the videos and thumbnails on the web client.  I currently have 3 videos uploaded and encoded to my storage and their info stored in my CMS.

My question is, how should I handle the SaS expiration for access to these assets?

my options:

1. change all sas created to expire in TimeSpan.MaxValue and delete all assets CMS data and reupload and reencode (I'm in very early alpha so nobody would notice).
2. Update the SaS expiration dates periodically with a web job or worker role to add 30 days to expiration and update all urls in the CMS every time they are close to expiration.
3. ????

I guess I'm not totally sure what the benefits to the second option are except that if people take my SaS Uri it would only work for a short time.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting here.

A stored access policy provides an additional level of control over shared access signatures on the server side. Establishing a stored access policy serves to group shared access signatures and to provide additional restrictions for signatures that are bound by the policy. You can use a stored access policy to change the start time, expiry time, or permissions for a signature, or to revoke it after it has been issued.

The following storage resources support stored access policies:
• Containers. Note that a stored access policy on a container can be associated with a shared access signature granting permissions to the container itself or to the blobs it contains.

• Queues

• Tables and table entity ranges

For more details on working with stored access policies, see Use a Stored Access Policy.

For reference, please check this link
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn140256.aspx
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj721951.aspx
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee393341.aspx

Hope this helps you.

Girish Prajwal